# I cannot unmap a key combination `y<C-G>`

Tags: key-bindings

When i check my mappings with

```
:verb nmap y
```

i get:

```
n  y<C-G>      *@:call setreg(v:register, <SNR>104_recall())<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive-2.2/plugin/fugitive.vim
```

I try to unmap it with `:unmap y<C-G>` and with `:unmap y<C-g>`, but it has no effect and i get the error `E31: No such mapping`.

How can i remove this mapping?  Why doesn't `:unmap y<C-G>` work here?

Comment: It turns out there is a related [ticket](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/394) for `fugitive` plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the mapping is local to a buffer as it was [defined](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/841adb49add27ccc45e73e231d02103f1be987c4/plugin/fugitive.vim#L200) with the argument `<buffer>`.
When you type `:unmap y<C-G>`, you ask Vim to unmap a global mapping whose `{lhs}` is `y<C-G>`, but there's probably no such global mapping on your system hence the error.

If you want to unmap the local mapping, you have to use the same argument `<buffer>` which was used to define it: `:unmap <buffer> y<C-G>`

Edit:

To automate the process you could install an autocmd watching the events `VimEnter`, `BufNewFile` and `BufReadPost`. It would test if the mapping exists `if !empty(maparg('y<C-G>', 'n'))`, before trying to delete it. It could give something like:

```
augroup custom_fugitive
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,BufNewFile,BufReadPost * if !empty(maparg('y<C-G>', 'n')) | unmap <buffer> y<C-G>| endif
augroup END
```

You couldn't write this in your `vimrc` because the latter is sourced before your plugins which would override anything you do. Instead you would have to write it inside `~/.vim/after/plugin/mappings.vim`. The filename (`mappings.vim`) doesn't matter, only the directory is important (`~/.vim/after/plugin/`).

Edit 2:

As your last [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/i-cannot-unmap-a-key-combination-yc-g#comment11936_7276) says it, it seems there's another way to disable the mapping. `fugitive` install the mappings `<C-R><C-G>` and `y<C-G>` only if `g:fugitive_no_maps` is different than zero. So if you include `let g:fugitive_no_maps=1` inside your `vimrc`, `y<C-G>` should not be defined.

Comment: The `autocmd` solution more or less works (except for the first matched file after [`lvim`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18213/event-after-lvim-has-opened-first-file)). From `~/.vimrc`. I don't see why attach to `VimEnter` event. Also, `BufReadPost` doesn't seem to be any much better than `BufRead`. And it makes sense to stress that no trailing spaces after `unmap` is allowed. Anyways, better solution is to put `unmap`s into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/FILETYPE.vim` (**ft**).