# Unmap netrw-c in vinegar.vim

Tags: key-bindings, netrw, plugin-unimpaired

I am using following vim plugins `vinegar` and `unimpaired`.

When I enter a netrw directory listing with `-`, the mappings of `unimpaired` starting with `c` (e.g. toggle line numbers with `con`)  do not work because netrw has mapped the single letter `c` (`:h netrw-c`).

I'd like to patch `vinegar` to add an unmapping for the `c` mapping of netrw.

For completeness I give here the mapping of `c` as done in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/netrw.vim`:

`nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> c  :<c-u>call <SID>NetrwLcd(b:netrw_curdir)<cr>`

I have tried to add in `plugin/vinegar.vim` to the `function! s:setup_vinegar() abort` following line

`nunmap c`

However, this does not work. This might be an issue of the load or evaluation order of vinegar w.r.t. netrw.

**UPDATE Sept 2018**

Netrw v162 has changed the mapping to `netrw-cd` and therefore I do not need this anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out while writing my question. Answer is given here: [I cannot unmap a key combination `y<C-G>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/i-cannot-unmap-a-key-combination-yc-g)

`nunmap <buffer> c` works.

```
❯ git diff
diff --git a/plugin/vinegar.vim b/plugin/vinegar.vim
index 28adce4..7afeafc 100644
--- a/plugin/vinegar.vim
+++ b/plugin/vinegar.vim
@@ -98,6 +98,7 @@ function! s:setup_vinegar() abort
   xnoremap <buffer> . <Esc>: <C-R>=<SID>escaped(line("'<"), line("'>"))<CR><Home>
   nmap <buffer> ! .!
   xmap <buffer> ! .!
+  nunmap  <buffer> c
   nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cg :exe 'keepjumps cd ' .<SID>fnameescape(b:netrw_curdir)<CR>
   nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cl :exe 'keepjumps lcd '.<SID>fnameescape(b:netrw_curdir)<CR>
```